# How to check in Lua if there are multiple elements in a table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I made a program, which checks if in table has (for example) "A" and a "B" in itself. But it doesn't works.

Here's code:

```
function inTable(t,e)
    return t[e] ~= nil
end

--Example
local table_ = {"A","B"}

if inTable(table_,"A") and inTable(table_,"B") then
    --Do some stuff
end
```

Please, help me.

I tried everything but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Create table as `local table_ = {["A"]=1,["B"]=1}` and your code will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if those exist as keys. You should be checking if they exist as values. You can change the function to this

```
function inTable(t,e)
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        if v == e then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

Also, in case you didn't know

```
local table_ = {"A","B"}
```

is equivalent to

```
local table_ = {[1] = "A", [2] = "B"}
```